# Write a PL/SQL Proc and calling a function within the proc. The input is productid. prints out the customer names who have ordered Product ID

Tags: oracle, plsql

4 tables

```
customer - custid (PK), customer_name
order- orderid(pk), custid(fk)
orderline-orderid(pk,fk), productid(pk,fk)
product-productid(pK)
```

This is the function

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_customer_name(cust_id IN S_ORDER_T.ORDER_ID%TYPE) 
    RETURN VARCHAR
    IS 
    cname VARCHAR (50);
    BEGIN
      SELECT customer_name
      INTO   cname
      FROM   s_order_t o
         INNER JOIN s_customer_t c
         ON (o.customer_id = c.customer_id)
      WHERE o.order_id = cust_id;

      RETURN cname;
    EXCEPTION
       WHEN no_data_found THEN
       RETURN NULL;
    END;
```

Procedure* calling the function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE print_all_customers(cust_id IN s_order_t.order_id%TYPE)
IS
cnames VARCHAR (50);
BEGIN
   cnames := get_customer_name(cust_id);
   IF cnames > 0 THEN
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (cnames);
   ELSE
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('NO Customer FOUND');
   END IF;
END;

BEGIN
   print_all_customers (1);
END;
```

/*Do I need to change the function to join the other tables?*/

Comment: Please provide full ddl for the tables (the actual "create table" statements and enough sample data to work with) - that way anyone trying to help you can just copy and run the scripts in his environment. No developer likes typing... 
Are you getting any errors ? Where are you stuck ?

Comment: Also take a look at https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions and see if that applies.

Comment: I am stuck on calling the function. When i execute the anonymous program my output is no customer found

Answer (score 0):

You have mixed up the ORDER_ID and the CUST_ID; in a normal system, those values are not related in any way. And since you already have the CUST_ID, you do not need to join it to the orders table:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_customer_name(p_cust_id IN NUMBER)
    RETURN VARCHAR2
    IS 
    cname VARCHAR (50);
    BEGIN
      SELECT customer_name
      INTO   cname
      FROM   s_customer_t c
      WHERE  c.cust_id = p_cust_id;

      RETURN cname;
    EXCEPTION
       WHEN no_data_found THEN
       RETURN NULL;
    END;
```

And you most probably are looking for the fact if there is a return value or not. I would suggest this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE print_all_customers(cust_id IN s_order_t.cust_id%TYPE)
IS
cnames VARCHAR (50);
BEGIN
   cnames := nvl(get_customer_name(cust_id), 'NO Customer FOUND');
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (cnames);
END;
```

But this only gives you 1 customer and not multiple as indicated in the name of the second procedure.